# swagger custom layout from scala-rho

Tags: scala, layout, routes, swagger, customization

I have a nice and simple API swagger standard layout documentation url, auto generated by the rho-routes swagger support. I want to customize the layout with let's say colors, logo, phrases and examples.

In my scala backend the SwaggerUI service is generated by this:

```
    case GET -> Root =>
      implicitly[Applicative[F]].pure(
        Response[F]()
        .withStatus(Status.SeeOther)
        .withHeaders(Location(Uri.fromString(
          s"${webjarPath}/swagger-ui/3.40.0/index.html?url=${swaggerApiJsonPath}&layout=BaseLayout").right.get)
        )
      )
  }
```

Is it possible to customize this "BaseLayout" direclty from the backend without importing a React dependency? If not: can I redirect the whole thing on my website to customize it from a ReactJS repo? If yes, how? Do I need a swagger npm integration? I'm a backend dev and I'm not very solid on FE infrastructures matters.

I'd appreciate someone to pointing me some articles or solutions I can study and apply with this case. Thanks all

Comment: I would just download SwaggerUi distrib, customize it and store it as an asset in your project rather than using webjar or npm. Less easy to keep up to date but no need for complex build setup.

Answer (score 0):

You serve a webjar which is easy to set up but difficult (if not impossible, I'm no expert) to customize.

What you can do to at least serve a customized Swagger UI, is handle it like any Play Twirl template:

- add all the Swagger frontend resources needed in your project:

find the links in the `/app/views/index.scala.html` contents below. I have:

```
ls public/swagger-ui 
swagger-ui-bundle.js  swagger-ui.js
oauth2-redirect.html  swagger-ui.css        swagger-ui-standalone-preset.js
```

- call the template from your controller:

See https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.8.x/ScalaTemplates as well

```
  def api: Action[AnyContent] =
    Action { implicit request =>
      Ok(views.html.index(s"https://${appConfig.apiUrl}", giveItSomeArgs)
    }
```

- customize your Swagger in the Twirl template:

mine is in `/app/views/index.scala.html`:

```
@import play.api.libs.json.JsValue
@import play.api.libs.json.Json
@(apiUrl: String, giveItSomeArgs: Set[String])


<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Swagger UI</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="assets/swagger-ui/swagger-ui.css" >
    <link rel="icon" type="image/png" href="../favicon-32x32.png" sizes="32x32" />
    <link rel="icon" type="image/png" href="../favicon-16x16.png" sizes="16x16" />
    <style>
      html
      {
        box-sizing: border-box;
        overflow: -moz-scrollbars-vertical;
        overflow-y: scroll;
      }

      *,
      *:before,
      *:after
      {
        box-sizing: inherit;
      }

      body
      {
        margin:0;
        background: #fafafa;
      }
    </style>
  </head>

  <body>
    <div id="swagger-ui"></div>

    <script src="assets/swagger-ui/swagger-ui-bundle.js"> </script>
    <script src="assets/swagger-ui/swagger-ui-standalone-preset.js"> </script>
    <script>
    window.onload = function() {
      // Begin Swagger UI call region
      const ui = SwaggerUIBundle({
        url: "/assets/openapi.json",
        dom_id: '#swagger-ui',
        deepLinking: true,
        presets: [
          SwaggerUIBundle.presets.apis,
          SwaggerUIStandalonePreset
        ],
        plugins: [
          SwaggerUIBundle.plugins.DownloadUrl,
          {
            statePlugins: {
              spec: {
                wrapActions: {
                  updateJsonSpec: function(oriAction, system) {
                    return (spec) => {
                      // change spec.servers here to add new entry, use concat to put it as the first & default one
                        spec.servers = [{url: "@apiUrl"}]
                        spec.components.schemas["swagger"]["docs"]["are"]["very"]["dynamic"] =  @Html(Json.toJson(giveItSomeArgs).toString);

                      return oriAction(spec)
                    }
                  }
                }
              }
            }
          }
        ],
        layout: "StandaloneLayout",
        onComplete: function() {
        }
      })
      // End Swagger UI call region


      window.ui = ui
    }
  </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

There's your layout `StandaloneLayout` so I guess you have a handle there. You can add all the JavaScript in the world and knock yourself out. Check the Swagger docs on how to customize the layout.

Not sure about the whole React thing you suggest, that's another thing.

Comment: Sadly I'm not using Play framework, but pure sbt scala. I can see in the swagger library files all the js and css style but I'm concerned on how to customize it without this handle you provide (thanks btw). I'm currently tryin my second guessed solution: I'm importing the swagger-ui module in an npm project and customizing it from there (hooking my generated index html page from the BE). I'll keep this updated